# System of first order differential equation with 3 variables (2 indepedent and 1 dependent)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I would like some help on comprehending this question as well as a push in the right direction. The question gave a system of first-order differential equation.

$x(t)' = 4x(t) - 3y(t)+6e^{2t}$

$y(t)' = 4x(t)-6y(t)$

The question asked me to find the 2nd inhomogeneous equation that satisfies x(t). Does this mean the answer should all be in terms of $x$? I tried focusing on the $x$ and differentiating it with respect to $t$.

so $x(t)' = 4x(t) - 3y(t)'+6e^{2t}$ becomes:

$x(t)'' = 4x(t)' - 3y(t)'+12e^{2t}$

for simplicity sake, I will write x(t) as x and y(t) as y.

After that step, I replaced the $y'$ in the $x''$ equation with the rearranged $y'$ from the original question into the differentiated $x'$ equation.
This gives:

$x''=4x'-3(4x-6(\frac{1}{-3}(x'-4x-6e^{2t})+12e^{2t}$

this cancels down to:

$x''=4x'-12x+2x'-8x$

but if you move everything to one side, it becomes

$x''-6x'+20x=0$

this is a second-order homogenous equation, so I don't quite know where I went wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your third line you wrote the original first line but with an extra dash on the $y$ which shouldn't be there. Although your fourth line is correct, you have substituted an incorrect expression for $y'$ due to this error, and that's where it all went wrong...

I assume you can fix this?

Comment: right, so the answer would be $x''+2x'+12x = 48e^{2t}$ then? Thank you so much! But isn't this also the solution to the systems of 1st order DEs? I don't quite understand what they want since it asked for that next. Would solving the inhomogeneous equation be considered as a gernal solution?

Comment: Yes I got the same. You now need to solve this second order DE for $x$ and use that to obtain the solution for $y$. Without knowing any initial conditions you will only be able to get general solutions.